# single-instance Thread implementation

Tags: java, android, multithreading, singleton

I have an android app which starts a thread that performs some networking like opening a ServerSocket and listening to it. 
Many different activities and services of that app have to be able to communicate with that thread, hence i had to implement some mechanism of sharing that thread over different parts.
Right now i have the following method which searches for an existing instance of the thread and in case of failure starts one

```
static public NodeReceiverThread getThread(){
    for (Thread t : Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet()){
        if(t.getName().equals(threadName)){
            return (NodeReceiverThread) t;
        }
    }
    NodeReceiverThread th = new NodeReceiverThread();

    th.start();
    return th;
}
```

Not it struck my mind that i could aswell use a singleton, which would save me some performance, but that would put me under the risk that the thread may be killed at some point but still exist in memory.

Is my example an acceptable way of implementing such a mechanism?

Is there any other, better way?

Comment: I think you don't need that iteration. If the thread must be only one just create it at the beginning, for example on MainActivity onCreate(), and pass the Thread variable to the parts that need to use it.

Comment: The issue with the idea is that the thread might be requested by different components that are not related to each other.